# How can I check if the text contains at least one A to Z letter?

Tags: php, regex

How can I write this in PHP?

```
if ($text contains at least one letter from A to Z, regardless of numbers or other characters)
    echo 'Yes';
else
    echo 'No';
```

Please help.

Comment: preg_match() see examples in manual.

Comment: I have no idea. I don't want to make an array with the letters and check. This doesn't seem as an ideal solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something that will help

```
preg_match("/[a-z]/i",$text);
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/i', $variable)) {

      echo 'Yes';
}
else {

      echo 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use preg_match() function

```
if (preg_match('/[a-z]/i', $text))
    echo "Matches";
else
    echo "No matches";
```